# Soft Keyboard doesn't pop up automatically

Tags: android

Layout is declared like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.guna.testapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:hint="@string/action_settings"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity declared like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And `Activity` added in manifest as like this.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I run this app I am getting following output.

[image]

I don't know why soft keyboard doesn't pop up automatically.

Comment: i think u should remove  <requestFocus /> in ur xml .may be its work

Comment: @PrashantRP I tried.. Doesn't work

Comment: android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"    ..try this in ur layout

Answer (score 0):

To force the soft keyboard to appear, you can use

```
 EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: No, I doesn't want to force the system, I just wanted to know why this code doesn't pop up the keyboard automatically.

Comment: you have to remove this line your xml   <requestFocus />

Comment: @Gunaseelan check it in other devices,

Comment: @GowthamanM I have checked with 2 devices, one is Nexus 5x(Nougat) and Redmi 3S(Marshmallow)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your edittext and try

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <activity
 android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />       
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

or in your activity

EditText actionSettings= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(actionSettings, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line inside your manifests Activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```